# rvm install ruby : error 'rvm make -j4'

Tags: ruby, archlinux

I have to work on differents projects for office, so I have to use rvm to work on differents ruby versions.

I use to work on ruby 2.2.3 but I have some really big troubles to install 2.1.0 using rvm.

Here is the error, it happens during the compilation

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/stasza_p/.rvm/log/1473084668_ruby-2.1.0/make.log
#define LONG2FIX(i) INT2FIX(i)
                    ^~~~~~~
  constdefs.c:21:6: note : in expansion of macro ‘LONG2FIX’
     LONG2FIX(n))
     ^~~~~~~~
constdefs.c:1715:50: note : in expansion of macro ‘INTEGER2NUM’
rb_define_const(rb_mSockConst, "EAI_SYSTEM", INTEGER2NUM(EAI_SYSTEM));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
linking shared-object socket.so
make[2] : leaving folder « /home/stasza_p/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0/ext/socket »
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2] : leaving folder « /home/stasza_p/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0/ext/ripper »
make[1] : leaving folder « /home/stasza_p/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0 »
make: *** [uncommon.mk:180: build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: me three- arch so sucks

Comment: I use chruby now, it's a equivalent to rvm.